# Wikipedia's bibliography style

Tags: biblatex, citing

I am wondering if it possible to define citation style that is similar of wikipedias. In other words, I want to use the `plain` bibliography style in which the citated autor to appear as a footnote mark

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

test test \textcite{einstein}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `\usepackage[autocite=superscript]{biblatex}` and then using `\autocite{}` instead of `\textcite{}` in text?

Comment: yeap it worked ;)

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf you can post your recommendation as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[autocite=superscript]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}

\begin{document}

test test \autocite{einstein}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine this with an APA style reference page?